# How does tf.contrib.seq2seq.gather_tree work?

Tags: tensorflow, beam-search

How exactly does `gather_tree` in `contrib.seq2seq` work? I can see that it takes the predicted ids and beam parent ids and somehow returns the final beams, but what's actually going underneath the hood? There doesn't seem to be any Python code base I could examine to figure it out. The [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/gather_tree) isn't very explanatory;

Is there any code source for `tf.contrib.seq2seq.gather_tree`? I am using TensorFlow 1.3 and looking inside `gen_beam_search_ops.py` doesn't seem helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The codes are detailed as follows:

```py
def gather_tree_py(values, parents):
  """Gathers path through a tree backwards from the leave nodes. Used
  to reconstruct beams given their parents."""

  beam_length = values.shape[0]
  num_beams = values.shape[1]
  res = np.zeros_like(values)
  res[-1, :] = values[-1, :]
  for beam_id in range(num_beams):
    parent = parents[-1][beam_id]
    for level in reversed(range(beam_length - 1)):
      res[level, beam_id] = values[level][parent]
      parent = parents[level][parent]
  return np.array(res).astype(values.dtype)


def gather_tree(values, parents):
  """Tensor version of gather_tree_py"""

  res = tf.py_func(
      func=gather_tree_py, inp=[values, parents], Tout=values.dtype)
  res.set_shape(values.get_shape().as_list())
  return res
```

[github: seq2seq beam_search](https://github.com/google/seq2seq/blob/master/seq2seq/inference/beam_search.py)